# How to reset() textarea in jquery,ajax and CI

Tags: jquery, ajax

here is my code only textarea reset not working please help me this is my only problem

```
$('#cleardata').click(function(){
        $('#myForm')[0].reset();
        $('#codnumbering')[0].reset();
        $('#newtitle')[0].reset();
        $('#newdesc')[0].reset();
        $('#company_id')[0].reset();
        $('#location_id')[0].reset();
        $('textarea[name=title]')[0].reset();
        $('textarea[name=description]')[0].reset();
        $('textarea[name=title]').val("");
        $('textarea[name=description]').val("");                       
});
```

Comment: `$('textarea').empty()` instead of `reset()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess instead of resetting each and every element of from, you should take the type = reset button in form.

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset the form">
```

Answer (score 0):

Text area cannot be cleared with reset() You can set its val or text

```
$("#mytextarea").text('');
```

or

```
$("#mytextarea").val('');
```

or

```
 $("#mytextarea").empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

To use val() to clear the values.

```
$("#textareaId").val('');
```